# What exactly does it mean for packages to be conflicting?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I installed a package and pacman spit out a message like this:

```
looking for conflicting packages...
:: packageX and packageY are in conflict. Remove packageY? [y/N]
```

I already managed to install the package but this got me thinking:
What does it mean when packages are in conflict and how does pacman detect these conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the maintainer thinks that the two packages cannot be installed together. The two packages probably install one or more equally named files. Mostly they install the same command: `/usr/bin/package`.

For that reason the maintainer puts that file to the 'conflicts array' of the `PKGBUILD` which is matched against the 'provides array' of other packages. Have a look here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD#conflicts